# how to input string, output int, use array python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.4

Someone can help me to complete this source code
am input String, change to array list, and output that int in that table

```
x = input()

y = list(x)

table = {" ":270,

         "a":0,
         "b":90,
         "c":180,
         "d":270,
         "e":0,
         "f":90,
         "g":180,
         "h":270,
         "i":0,
         "j":90,
         "k":180,
         "l":270,
         "m":0,
         "n":90,
         "o":180,
         "p":270,
         "q":0,
         "r":90,
         "s":180,
         "t":270,
         "u":0,
         "v":90,
         "w":180,
         "x":270,
         "y":0,
         "z":90,}



for i in range(len(y)):
    print(y[i])
    print("{["+y[i]+"]}".format(table))
```

Error at

```
print("{["+y[i]+"]}".format(table))
```

Example: for input `abc` the expected output should be:

```
a
0
b
90
c
180
```

Comment: You should add an input example and the desired output. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `range(len(y))` will fail because indexes of lists start at `0` not at `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` has higher priority that the string concatenation `+`.

This expression `"{["+y[i]+"]}".format(table)` is actually evaluated as:

```
"{["+y[i]+("]}".format(table))
```

which is not what you want.

You must use parenthesis to force the concatenation **before** applying format method:

```
print(("{["+y[i]+"]}").format(table))
```

BTW, I assume that it was a simplified example, because using format here is really overkill, as this would produce the same output:

```
for c in y:
    print(c)
    print(table[c])
```

Comment: thanks sir..

always use parenthesis before format method.

btw iam still newbie

Comment: Explanation is accurate, and that works... in the sense that it produces the expected output. But using a `.format()` to fetch a mapped value from a dict...  that it about the most horrible way to do it.

Comment: @Guillaume: I assumed it was a simplified example to demonstrate a problem... Anyway I've edited my post :-)

Comment: @Guillaume : sir , why iam include new array (int), i change "a":0,"b":90, "c":180, to "1":0, "2":90, "3":180

error at from array(0) (from ealry)

wheter use int can't in array list?

Answer (score 1):

I‘m not sure what you want to do. But maybe something like this?

```
for i in y:
    print(i, table[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

This code fails and is far from elegant:

```
y = list(x)
for i in range(len(y)):
    print(y[i])
    print("{["+y[i]+"]}".format(table))
```

In Python you generally don't need to do C style iteration over a string, using a incrementing index. Just iterate over the string directly:

```
for letter in x:
    print("my letter is", letter)
    print("my integer is", table[letter])
```

And to convert each letter to the matching integer, generating a list, then printing it:

```
my_int_list = [table[letter] for letter in x]
print(my_int_list)
```

Last remark, you should name your variables with descriptive names, `x` and `y` are more than confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you wanted to convert every element in y to int. You can use list comprehension for that:

```
y = [int(x) for x in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that answer for your question will be this code:

```
x = str(input('Input string\n'))

table = {" ": 270,
         "a": 0,
         "b": 90,
         "c": 180,
         "d": 270,
         "e": 0,
         "f": 90,
         "g": 180,
         "h": 270,
         "i": 0,
         "j": 90,
         "k": 180,
         "l": 270,
         "m": 0,
         "n": 90,
         "o": 180,
         "p": 270,
         "q": 0,
         "r": 90,
         "s": 180,
         "t": 270,
         "u": 0,
         "v": 90,
         "w": 180,
         "x": 270,
         "y": 0,
         "z": 90}


for element in x:
    if element in table:
        print '{}\n{}'.format(element, int(table[element]))
```